# Lifecycle of a broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I want to have a `BroadcastReceiver` that has to be active forever (100%). Now if I have this registered in the Android manifest will that be the case, or it will get killed when the app itself is destroyed by the Android framework?

Now, I also have a service running in foreground all the time. Will that make sure that my app is never destroyed? And in turn will that make sure that my receiver which is registered in the Android manifest will remain active forever.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a `BroadcastReceiver` ([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)) which is on the manifest is always active and it works even if the activity is no longer running (think about receivers for the intent action `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` which triggers every time the phone is switched on).
Receivers which are defined and registered dinamically only work when the app is running (such as [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)'s `registerReceiver(...)` approach).

See [receiver element documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html) which states:

> Declares a broadcast receiver (a BroadcastReceiver subclass) as one of
> the application's components. Broadcast receivers enable applications
> to receive intents that are broadcast by the system or by other
> applications, even when other components of the application are not
> running.

[Documentation about services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) says:

> A foreground service is a service that's considered to be something
> the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for the system
> to kill when low on memory

So it is likely that the system won't kill the running app to which the service refers.

Comment: Just want to add that on later versions of Android, BroadcastReceivers in the manifest are not active until the app has run at least once.

Comment: Thanks fiipi for a precise answer. I had gone throught the docs but the docs are increasing in size everyday, and lot of unwanted info being added. I am comparing this to the very intial docs which were very clear. I also mentioned this in my question but it was edited :) Thanks Once again.

Comment: Is there a way to disable/re-enable a statically registered broadcastreceiver? I'd like to receive notifications when a wifi scan is completed, but only when certain toggles are enabled in my app. It seems overkill to register statically, so that onReceive() is triggered every time a scan completes ~10-20seconds even though the toggle in the app means I take no action.

Comment: @BoomShaka You can dynamically register/unregister a broadcast at the toggle reset.