# Android Foreground Service check if created

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, foreground-service

I have a service in my app, its a medicinal app and the service is supposed to run the whole time the app is installed without being killed.
So I tried few approaches, tried with a regular service returning `START_STICKY` but that didnt exactly recreated the service as it is supposed to be. Then I decided to try it with foreground service.
I am creating it win the service onStartCommand like this

```
    startForeground(FOREGROUND_ID, buildForegroundNotification());
    return START_STICKY;
}

private Notification buildForegroundNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    b.setOngoing(true);
    b.setContentTitle("My App");
    b.setContentText("Therapy is running");
    b.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    return (b.build());
}
```

so I have two questions:
- Can the foreground service be killed by Android?
- How do I check if the notification is already created so it doesn't create it every time the service is starting (the service is being recreated multiple times when the Activity is also running, because it is actively communicating with it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25990195/lifecyccle-of-a-broadcast-reciever/25990699#25990699).

Second  question: I suppose you're using `myNotificationManager.notify(int id, Notification notification)`. The ID field is used to identify the types of notification you want to display, so setting the same ID for the same type of notification will replace the old notification with the newly created one (if the old one is still displayed) or simply display a new one (see [NotificationManager docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html)).